# Geometric argument why rotation by 180 degrees commutes with reflections

Tags: group-theory, geometry

I have no trouble determining the center of the dihedral group $D_n$ using an algebraic argument ($R_{180}$ is self-inverse).

But I've been trying (without success) to find the geometric explanation why rotation by $180$ degrees commutes with any reflection.

> Is there a geometric argument why rotation by $180$ commutes with any
>   reflection in $D_n$?

I have observed that this rotation maps each reflection axis to itself but I don't see how to proceed from there (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. :) It may help to show that reflections across *orthogonal* lines commute: If $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are reflections in orthogonal lines through a point $p$, then $R_{1} R_{2} = H_{p}$, the half-turn about $p$, and the same argument applies to $R_{2} R_{1}$.

Now if $R$ is an arbitrary reflection across a line through the origin, let $R^{\perp}$ denote reflection about the orthogonal line through the origin, decompose the half-turn about the origin as $H_{0} = RR^{\perp}$, and observe that each factor commutes with $R$.

(The algebraic version, of course, is that $H_{0}$ is induced by the scalar matrix $-I$, which commutes with every linear transformation, particularly with every linear reflection.)

Comment: Thank you, this helps. A lot. The only reason why I haven't accepted is because now I'm stuck on working out the angle of rotation of a product of two reflections :-D

Comment: It suffices for your purposes to show that $(R^{\perp}R)^{2} = R^{\perp}RR^{\perp}R$ is the identity, if that seems easier. :) (One reason is that $(R^{\perp})^{2} R^{2}$ is clearly the identity, and in a group, $(ab)^{2} = a^{2} b^{2}$ if and only if $ba = ab$.)

Comment: So $H_0$ is $R_{180}$ in your notation, right? So we decompose $R_{180}$ as two $90$ degree rotations which also happen to be reflections. So far so good. Let's say $R_{180} = FF^\bot$ where I use $F$ to denote a reflection. Now let $F'$ be a different reflection. Why is it that $$ F'FF^\bot = FF^\bot F'$$?

Comment: Oh no, you start with any reflection and use it to decompose $R_{180}$, right?

Comment: I think the answer to your second comment is "yes". :) First, $H_{0}$ is indeed $R_{180}$, the half-turn about the origin. I'll switch to $F$ to denote a reflection. If $F$ and $F^{\perp}$ are reflections having mutually orthogonal axes, the claim is $FF^{\perp} = H_{0}$ (no matter which pair of orthogonal axes are chosen). So, if $F$ is an arbitrary reflection, decompose $H_{0} = FF^{\perp}$, the composition of _$F$ itself_ with the reflection across the line orthogonal to the "axis" of $F$; that composition clearly commutes with $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Try labeling the vertices of the regular $n$-gon, $\{1,...,n\}$ and the observe the action of the two group operations on any vertex, in both orders. See if the vertex mapping is the same.

For a start, you can try using choosing the reflection to occur about the line of symmetry passing through vertex $1$, and then noting that $1$ maps to itself, $2$ maps to $n-1$, $3$ maps to $n-2$, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I did that *before* I asked the question. With a square. The thing is looking at concrete examples is exactly what I don't want to do. I am looking for the geometric argument that explains the $n$-gon case.

Comment: Well if you run the argument for each of the $n$ vertices I think it should hold generally